# Issue in "apps overview" ( applications windows are white)

Tags: launcher, recents-screen, nova-launcher

Redmi Note 10 Pro, Android 13, MIUI 14, Nova Launcher Prime.

What happen: in the "recent app overview", suddenly, some applications are shown as white windows:

[image]
[image]

What I tried to do:

- Clear Nova's cache
- Clear Nova's data (and start it from scratch)
- Restart Nova
- Restart the system

This issue doesn't occurs if I use MIUI's default launcher.

I sent an email to Nova's Developer, which told me:

> The reason for this is because stock launchers have complete access to
> the system whereas 3rd party launchers don't. The recent apps screen
> is controlled by Android and your device OEM and is tied to the stock
> launcher of your device.
>
> The issue you are experiencing will happen in any and all 3rd party
> launchers (not the stock launcher), not just Nova.

As I've said, this happened suddenly: two days ago I didn't had this issue; I have to give some specific permission to Nova Launcher? How can I solve?

Comment: Since the developer seems to think it should have been happening all along, have you tried other launcher apps? Or reinstalling Nova?

Comment: @jlehenbauer Yes: I tried other launchers and the issue doesn't occurs. Also tried to reinstall Nova and the issue is still present.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that using 3rd-party launchers may affect the recent screen since I can't really think any relation between them. Instead, there's [a similar question about a blank/white recent screen due to *screen rotation*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/218582/44325).

Comment: @AndrewT. I have a news: yesterday, after innumerable reboots, the issue went away; then yesterday night, where i leave the phone untouched for eight hours, i wake up and the issue is back.